# Assign css class if a word begins with @

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on twitter web app. in paragraph if i mention like @username I want to highlight the @username in the paragraph using css. what is easiest to do that. i have jquery but can't figure how. thanks

Comment: using jquery only if the page is dynamic if not mean end user is doing nothing in it then best use CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by, create a css class named "highlight" which will used for highlighting
and grab the paragraph content. and replace with

```
$(function(){
    var str = paragraphtext;
    str = str.replace(/\B@([\w-]+)/gm, '<span class="highlight">@$1</span>');
    alert(str);
});
```

Check this quick **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VdJaa/)**

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var str = jQuery('div#longertweet').html();
    str = str.replace(/\B@([\w-]+)/gm, '<span class="btn btn-info">@$1</span>');
    jQuery('div#longertweet').html(str);
    });​
    </script>`

Comment: thanks for your help and sorry for bugging you again. can you please tell, how to convert @username into hyperlink as well which links to http://twitter.com/username using jQuery

Comment: @ImranJafri, sorry for late reply, you can try `str = str.replace(/\B@([\w-]+)/gm, '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>');` for achieving it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible to do with just pure css.. You can - as rahul states - apply style to the entire paragraph... but to target the `@something` word directly with style isn't possible unless it is already wrapped with a dom element.

You're best bet is to seek this out with javascript and replace them with `<span class="user">@something</span>` ... which you can then target with css.

Answer (score 0):

Create a span with a class around such all word which you want to highlight, and assign the required css to the class.

example:

```
<p>This is text <span class="hl">@forsomeone</span> . 
You should also check <span class="hl">@abc</span> . 
What you say?</p>
```

and the css

```
.hl {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this jquery plugin

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html